# Documents visible but "doesn't exist"

Tags: couchbase

I have been developing my application from a dev sandbox and want to push the reference data from "dev" to "prod". I thought I'd succeeded by executing the following commands:

On my OSX dev machine:

```
cbbackup http://127.0.0.1:8091 ~/couchbase-reference-data -b reference_data -u username -p password
```

Again on my OSX dev machine:

```
cbrestore ~/couchbase-reference-data http://prod.server.com:8091/ -u password -p password
```

Now when I go to the admin console on production I see this:

[image]

Looks good at this point. However, if I click any of the "Edit Document" button things go tragically wrong:

[image]

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

### UPDATE:

I've noticed that now when I run the `cbrestore` command I get the following errors:

```
 2013-06-03 16:53:48,295: s0 error: CBSink.connect() for send: error: SASL auth exception: aws.internal-ip.com:11210, user: reference_data
 2013-06-03 16:53:48,295: s0 error: async operation: error: SASL auth exception: aws.internal-ip.com:11210, user: reference_data on sink:   http://prod.server.com:8091/(reference_data@127.0.0.1:8091)
error: SASL auth exception: aws.internal-ip.com:11210, user: reference_data
```

This reminds me that I think what I did was copy the ~/couchbase-reference-data directory to the production environment and then ran the `cbrestore` from there. I have just done that now and get the following confirmation:

```
  [####################] 100.0% (189/189 msgs)
bucket: reference_data, msgs transferred...
       :                total |       last |    per sec
 batch :                    1 |          1 |       16.1
 byte  :                36394 |      36394 |   585781.0
 msg   :                  189 |        189 |     3042.1
done
```

After this process, however, the problem still exists in the same manner as described before.

### UPDATE 2

I decided to delete, re-create, and re-import the bucket on production. All steps completed and I still have the same error but I'm wondering if the LOG file has any interesting information in it:

[image]

The things that stand out as interesting to me are:

1. The loading time was "0 seconds" ... as much as I'd like to believe that it may be a little too quick? It's not a ton of data but still.
2. The "module code" is named 'ns_memecached001' ... is that an issue? Memcached? I did double check that I set this up as a couchbase bucket. It is.

Comment: Never experienced such problem. But as workaround you can try to use XDCR instead of backup-restore. Or also you can try to write small util using any client library that gets all docs from your dev machine and writes it to production. I've wrote such util when Couchbase 2.0 was in DevPreview stage and cbbackup not worked at all.

Comment: I did give XDCR a try but got the message `Attention - Failed to grab remote bucket info from any of known nodes` when I tried to establish the connection. I suspect this is because the configuration on AWS uses internal IP addresses in its configuration.

Comment: Using the client library may end up being my only solution but I don't think that will allow me to move across views. Will it?

Comment: Access views could be easily taken from backup file called design.json from bucket folder and resore it via rest api with help of curl utility or something else that could do post request to url. See http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-designdoc-api.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if your destination server is not OS X, but e.g. Linux. Here you have to use the ["rehash"-extra-option](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/CLI/cbrestore-tween-opsys.html).

1. Backup your data on your dev machine (using `cbbackup`)
2. Copy the data to your prod machine
3. Restore the data with the `-x rehash=1` flag: (using `cbrestore -x rehash=1`)